# Qué está mal en este SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas. Estoy haciendo esta consulta, que no me esta devolviendo ningun resultado. Sin el `where` funciona perfecto y me devuelve la data de todos los demos y todos los details de cada demo, pero quiero ponerle un `where` para traer la información solo de 1 demo; es decir, el demo que corresponda a esa id y los detalles de ese demo.

- ¿Cuál es la relacion? La `id`.
- ¿Cuál es el error? Ninguno, simplemente no devuelve registros.
- ¿Estás seguro de que la `id` *'tvy'* existe en ambas tablas? 100% seguro.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT  `i`.`name`, 
        `i`.`id`, 
        `i`.`img`, 
        `i`.`cat_id`, 
        `d`.`description`, 
        `d`.`url` 
FROM `demos` i 
INNER JOIN `details` d 
    ON `i`.`id` = `d`.`demo_id` 
WHERE `i`.`id` = 'tvy' 
AND `d`.`demo_id` = 'tvy' 
ORDER BY `created_at` ASC
```

Comment: nada se ve mal. Y aunque sé que lo agregaste a tu pregunta, debo preguntar de nuevo: ¿Estás seguro que el id `'tvy'` existe en ambas tablas?, ¿te aparece en el resultado sin el `WHERE`?. Ojo que debe estar escrito tal cual, puede ser que exista el id `' tvy'` por ejemplo, o haya algún caracter no visible. Trata copiando el valor del resultado sin el `WHERE` en tu condición

Comment: por que en el where consultas si i.id = 'tvy' y además haces lo mismo para d.demo_id='tvy' si ya las estas relacionado en el inner join ?? solo bastaría que hicieras el where por uno solo

Comment: tal como dice @Lamak probablemente el valor no es igual, quizas diga 'tvy', pero quizas tenga un espacio o algo. Yo nunca recomendaría que el ID de una tabla fuera texto.

Comment: @Lamak muchas gracias era eso, tenia un espacio por algun motivo en ambas tablas antes de la id, si quieres colocalo como respuesta y te doy +1

Comment: @Lamak da tu respuesta para que puedan calificarte, saludos. Santiago, deberias usar un id numerico, te evitaras problemas futuros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nada se ve mal con tu consulta.

Y aunque sé que lo agregaste a tu pregunta, debo preguntar de nuevo: ¿Estás seguro que el id `'tvy'` existe en ambas tablas?, ¿te aparece en el resultado sin el `WHERE`?. Ojo que debe estar escrito tal cual, puede ser que exista el id `' tvy'` por ejemplo, o haya algún caracter no visible. Trata copiando el valor del resultado sin el `WHERE` en tu condición.

Y sí, como dice @Marcos, la consulta final es redundante, bastaría usar sólo:

```
WHERE `i`.`id` = 'tvy'
```

O

```
WHERE `d`.`demo_id` = 'tvy'
```

Comment: Yo agregaría, que el ID fuera numérico, sería el fin del problema.

Comment: En el 99% de los casos debe serlo. No sé si la mayoría de motores optimizarán sus consutas respecto a JOINs con varchar, pero al menos SQLS sí.

Comment: *'puede ser que exista el id ' tvy' por ejemplo, o haya algún caracter no visible'*. Como anillo al dedo ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sé que dices que está en ambos lados, pero ¿estás seguro que el id `tvy` está en ambas tablas? si no lo está, el `inner join` no te traerá el resultado. Por otro no es necesario que el `where` sea:

```
WHERE `i`.`id` = 'tvy' 
AND `d`.`demo_id` = 'tvy'
```

Es algo redundante.

Comment: La palabra es **redundante**.

Comment: jajaja casi. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Tal como indique antes, no es recomendable usar ID de texto, ya que hay muchas variables que pueden hacer caer tu consulta, como por ejemplo los espacios, mayusculas, etc.

Te dejo una ejemplo de como lo haría yo.

```
SELECT  `i`.`name`, 
    `i`.`id`, 
    `i`.`img`, 
    `i`.`cat_id`, 
    `d`.`description`, 
    `d`.`url` 
     FROM `demos` i 
     INNER JOIN `details` d 
      ON `i`.`id` = `d`.`demo_id` 
     WHERE trim(`i`.`id`) = 'tvy' 
     AND trim(`d`.`demo_id`) = 'tvy' 
    ORDER BY `created_at` ASC
```

Aunque ya estas haciendo en el INNER JOIN una relación, bastaría solo con filtrar por una y no por los ids.

En ese caso la consulta sería esta:

```
SELECT  `i`.`name`, 
        `i`.`id`, 
        `i`.`img`, 
        `i`.`cat_id`, 
        `d`.`description`, 
        `d`.`url` 
         FROM `demos` i 
         INNER JOIN `details` d 
          ON trim(`i`.`id`) = trim(`d`.`demo_id`) 
         WHERE trim(`i`.`id`) = 'tvy' 
        ORDER BY `created_at` ASC
```

Saludos,